# Visualize Rails schema.rb with tool/plugin/script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema, visualization

I am looking for a tiny tool/script/plugin to visualize my Rails schema.rb file so that our project does not have to maintain a separate diagram manually.

Do you have any experiences on that subject?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out [RailRoad](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/).

It creates diagrams for models and controllers. I bet it will do what you want. It produces DOT files which can be viewed with Graphviz or other programs.

I've had some success with it, but when you have a ton of models, you may need to do some manual rearrangement to get a decent looking diagram.

[image: RailRoad example]
<sub>(source: [rubyforge.org](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/diagrams/depot_models_full.png))</sub>

Comment: Accepting your answer. RailRoad looks promising. But how do you rearrange the model drawings? (in my case, it got complicated and messing pretty fast)

Answer (score 11):

Checkout RailRoady for a Rails 3 project. It's forked from RailRoad.

https://github.com/preston/railroady

Answer (score 1):

You can also checkout [Schemapper](http://github.com/NathanielWroblewski/schemapper) for Rails 3.0+

Answer (score 0):

Confirming the top answer as the way to go. 
You can take the DOT output from Railroad to [graphviz-dev.appspot.com](http://graphviz-dev.appspot.com/) to generate the image online.

As others have stated, it would be nice if you could manually rearrange the output.